# Linear regression on modified datas

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to create a linear regression on modified data.

My raw data is on a file called data.dat like that :

```
x,y
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
5,8
6,9
7,34
```

If I do something like the code below, I get the linear regression for the not modified data.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\pgfplotsset{legend style={fill=none, font=\tiny, legend pos=north east}}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        width=0.8\paperwidth, height=0.8\paperheight,
        ymin=0,
        xmin=0,
        xmajorgrids, xminorgrids, ymajorgrids,
    ]   

    \addplot table [col sep=comma, y expr= \thisrow{y}/((7.75)), x expr = \thisrow{x}^(2)]{data.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Huile/Eau, débit nul};
    \addplot table[col sep=comma,y={create col/linear regression}]{data.dat};
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}    


    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It give me this instead of a linear regression of my plot

[image]

Comment: ,@zeslayer See **Sec 3.3.4  Add a Selected Fit-line**, page 27 of the PGFPLOTS manual for how to include a regression plot.

Comment: On this page, they explain how to give weight to each point for the linear regression but not to fit to a modified curve no ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gonzalo Medina in this post : [plot and fit from pgfplottable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257539/plot-and-fit-from-pgfplottable), I did manage to do what I wanted.

The final code is :

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{document}




\begin{frame}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.dat}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new/.style={
create col/expr={\thisrow{x}^(2)}},
create on use/new2/.style={
create col/expr ={\thisrow{y}/((7.75))}
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=new,y=new2] {\loadedtable};
\addlegendentry{test};
\addplot table[x=new,y={create col/linear regression={y=new2}}] {\loadedtable};
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```