# plot and fit from pgfplottable

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, curve-fitting

I would like to plot a graph from data created inside `pgfplottable`.

I have one file of data `data.dat`:

```
x,y
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
5,8
6,9
7,34
```

And this code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.dat}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new/.style={
create col/expr={\thisrow{x}^(2)}},
create on use/new2/.style={
create col/expr ={\thisrow{y}/((7.75))}
}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So, I have, from my data, created two other columns of data.

Now, I would like to plot new in relation to new2 and make a fit of this plot.

Do someone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=new,y=new2] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x=new,y={create col/linear regression={y=new2}}] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{array}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x,y
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
5,8
6,9
7,34
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.dat}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new/.style={
create col/expr={\thisrow{x}^(2)}},
create on use/new2/.style={
create col/expr ={\thisrow{y}/((7.75))}
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=new,y=new2] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x=new,y={create col/linear regression={y=new2}}] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for the fit to be the fit of [new,new2], we need to write  \addplot table[x=new,y={create col/linear regression={y=new2}}] {\loadedtable}; Now it's completely solved.

Comment: @zeslayer True. The documentation suggests that pgfplots would pick the right x column from the previous plot, but evidently this was not the case. I updated the answer.